# in phpunit, is there a method similar to onconsecutivecalls for use inside the "with" method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, junit, pdo, phpunit

Using PHPUnit, I'm mocking the pdo, but I'm trying to find a way to prepare more than one database query statement.

```
$pdo = $this->getPdoMock();
$stmt = $this->getPdoStatementMock($pdo);

$pdo->expects($this->any())
    ->method('prepare')
    ->with($this->equalTo($title_query))
    ->will($this->returnValue($stmt));

$title_stmt = $pdo->prepare($title_query);
$desc_stmt = $pdo->prepare($desc_query);
```

I want to pass something similar to onConsecutiveCalls for the "with" method, so I can prepare multiple statements, as seen above.
How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can match consecutive invocations of the same method by writing separate expectations with `$this->at()` instead of `$this->any()`:

```
$pdo->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('prepare')
    ->with($this->equalTo($title_query))
    ->will($this->returnValue($stmt));

$pdo->expects($this->at(1))
    ->method('prepare')
    ->with($this->equalTo($desc_query))
    ->will($this->returnValue($stmt));

$title_stmt = $pdo->prepare($title_query);
$desc_stmt = $pdo->prepare($desc_query);
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for. Working great now. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the counter is per-mock across *all* method calls received to it. Thus if there are going to be two intervening calls to `$pdo`, you would use 0 and 3.

Comment: @David yes, you're right. Still worth mentioning is that only calls to methods that were `actually replaced` with mock implementation count.

Comment: I believe you can also combine `at()` with `any()`. I wanted the first call to a mock method to return false, and all subsequent calls to return true. So I used `at(0) ... will($this->returnValue(false)` and `any() ... will($this->returnValue(true)`.

Answer (score 16):

PHPUnit 4.1 got a new method `withConsecutive()`. From the [Test Double Chapter](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html):

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testFunctionCalledTwoTimesWithSpecificArguments()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('stdClass', array('set'));
        $mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
             ->method('set')
             ->withConsecutive(
                 array($this->equalTo('foo'), $this->greaterThan(0)),
                 array($this->equalTo('bar'), $this->greaterThan(0))
             );

        $mock->set('foo', 21);
        $mock->set('bar', 48);
    }
}
```

Each argument of `withConsecutive()` is for one call to the specified method.

Answer (score 13):

With more recent versions of PHPUnit, the accepted answer can be simplified quite a bit.

Plus, while it isn't immediately relevant to the original question, you can easily provide **different** return values for each method invocation via the `willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls` method.

```
$pdo->expects($this->exactly(2))
    ->method('prepare')
    ->withConsecutive(
        $this->equalTo($title_query),
        $this->equalTo($desc_query)
    )
    ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
        $stmt, // returned on the 1st call to prepare()
        $stmt  // returned on the 2nd call to prepare()
    );
```

Comment: This is a more appropriate and simple answer for more recent PHPUnit versions. Definitely easier.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I have found resembling what you ask is using the 'at':

```
$mock->expects($this->at(0))->method // etc
$mock->expects($this->at(1))->method // etc
```

So you set expectations for the first time it is called (at 0), the second time and so on.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of folks have noted that at($index) can be used for specific instances of calls to a method.  David H. and Vika clarified that $index counts ALL calls to ALL mocked methods of the object.

In addition, it may be worth noting that the [Test Doubles Chapter](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) of the PHPunit documentation has a warning note about this.  It points out that using at() should be done with caution, since it can lead to brittle tests that depend too much on the specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I use a dataProvider and need a variable numbers of executed queries that i can use to populate my provider, i want to provide an array of the queries that should be executed.
The problem with `withConsecutive` is that it takes a variable number of arrays, each one an array of arguments.

I solved it using the follwing code, this feels "hacky" but is working :

```
$withConsecutiveArgs = [
    [$this->equalTo($title_query)], 
    [$this->equalTo($desc_query)],
    ..., 
    N queries
];
$withConsecutiveReturns = [
    $title_stmt, 
    $desc_stmt,
    ...,
    N returns
];

$methodMock = $pdo->expects($this->exactly(count($args))->method('prepare');
$methodMock->getMatcher()->parametersMatcher = new \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_ConsecutiveParameters($withConsecutiveArgs);
$methodMock->will(new \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ConsecutiveCalls($withConsecutiveReturns));

$title_stmt = $pdo->prepare($title_query);
$desc_stmt = $pdo->prepare($desc_query);
...
$N_s_stmt = $pdo->prepare($N_s_query);
```

I hope it evolves correctly with future versions of PhpUnit (which is unsure, since i rely on internals of the lib, but that's the whole point of doing unit test, i may have to refactor it but production will not suffer from that)

Comment: This is it. This does work as expected without having to enumerate all the arguments.