# phpunit parametersMatcher for consecutive method calls

Tags: phpunit

Is there any way of configuring a phpunit parametersMatcher for consecutive calls on 1 Method?

e.g. on first Call parameter has to be "1", on second "2" .. I don't want to use "$this->at(x)" because I've got very much calls on my MockObject and i don't want to count for correct sequence (EveryTime I change the order of called Methods I probably would have to change the expected sequence).

Comment: In PHPUnit 4.1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24000011/2265374

Comment: thanks, I'm already using this :-)